# Convert date string into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, date, int

I'm trying to convert my date string into an array.

Date string: `var date = "2017,03,23";`

Desired result: `[2017,03,23]`

---

Here is what I tried:

```
var new_date = date.split(','); // result: ["2017", "03", "23"]
```

I want `[2017,03,23]`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do:

```js
var date = "2017,03,23";
var array = date.split(",").map(Number);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `parseInt` the `array`!

```js
var date = "2017,03,23";
date = date.split(',');
for(var i=0; i<date.length; i++) { date[i] = parseInt(date[i], 10); }
console.log(date);
```

Comment: I think `date.split(',').map(Number)` is somewhat shorter. ;-)

Comment: Little overloading in here for sure. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an array of `String`, instead of an array of `int`. You just need to convert the array you have into `int`s in a new array. Here's an example, using `parseInt()`:

```
var new_date = date.split(',');
for(i = 0; i < new_date.length; i++){
    new_date[i] = parseInt(new_date[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better and short way would be using

```js
var date ="2017,03,23";
var output = date.split(',').map(Number);
console.log(output);
```